# compare values based on nearest datetime

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I'm have two pandas dataframes, both with two columns: datetime and value (float). I want to substract the value of dataframe A from the value of dataframe B based on the nearest datetime.

Example:

```
dataframe A:
datetime | value
01-01-2016 00:00 | 10
01-01-2016 01:00 | 12
01-01-2016 02:00 | 14
01-01-2016 03:00 | 12
01-01-2016 04:00 | 12
01-01-2016 05:00 | 16
01-01-2016 06:00 | 18


dataframe B:
datetime | value
01-01-2016 00:20 | 5
01-01-2016 00:50 | -5
01-01-2016 01:20 | 12
01-01-2016 01:50 | 30
01-01-2016 02:20 | 1
01-01-2016 02:50 | 6
01-01-2016 03:50 | 0
```

In case of the first row of A, this would mean that the nearest datetime of B would also be the first row and thus: 10-5 = 5. In case of the fourth row of A (01-01-2016 3:00) this would mean that the sixth row of B is nearest and the difference would be: 12-6 = 6.

I currently do this using a for loop:

```
for i, row in data.iterrows():
    # i is the index, a Timestamp
    data['h'][i] = row['h'] - baro.iloc[baro.index.get_loc(i,method='nearest')]['h']
```

It works fine, but would it be possible to do this faster?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

new with pandas 0.19  `pd.merge_asof`

```
pd.merge_asof(dfa, dfb, 'datetime')
```

[image]

Comment: yeah, this one is WAY better!

Comment: wow! I fell in love with this function - it accepts `tolerance`: `pd.merge_asof(df1, df2, on='datetime', tolerance=pd.Timedelta('30 minute'))`

Answer (score 2):

IIUC you can use [reindex(..., method='nearest')](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) method if you are using Pandas version < 0.19.0, starting from 0.19.0 it definitely makes sense to use [pd.merge_asof](https://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/generated/pandas.merge_asof.html), which is much more convenient and much more efficient too:

```
df1 = df1.set_index('datetime')
df2 = df2.set_index('datetime')

In [214]: df1.join(df2.reindex(df1.index, method='nearest'), rsuffix='_right')
Out[214]:
                     value  value_right
datetime
2016-01-01 00:00:00     10            5
2016-01-01 01:00:00     12           -5
2016-01-01 02:00:00     14           30
2016-01-01 03:00:00     12            6
2016-01-01 04:00:00     12            0
2016-01-01 05:00:00     16            0
2016-01-01 06:00:00     18            0

In [224]: df1.value - df2.reindex(df1.index, method='nearest').value
Out[224]:
datetime
2016-01-01 00:00:00     5
2016-01-01 01:00:00    17
2016-01-01 02:00:00   -16
2016-01-01 03:00:00     6
2016-01-01 04:00:00    12
2016-01-01 05:00:00    16
2016-01-01 06:00:00    18
Name: value, dtype: int64

In [218]: merged = df1.join(df2.reindex(df1.index, method='nearest'), rsuffix='_right')

In [220]: merged.value.subtract(merged.value_right)
Out[220]:
datetime
2016-01-01 00:00:00     5
2016-01-01 01:00:00    17
2016-01-01 02:00:00   -16
2016-01-01 03:00:00     6
2016-01-01 04:00:00    12
2016-01-01 05:00:00    16
2016-01-01 06:00:00    18
dtype: int64
```

Comment: note that this is by definition includes forward and backward looks - so generally to use merge_asof with time series data if ordering matters

Comment: @Jeff, yeah, as i mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40468656/compare-values-based-on-nearest-datetime/40468794?noredirect=1#comment68182312_40468934) `merge_asof()` is a pure beauty